# How do I disable desktop icons? (no nautilus in gconf-editor)

Tags: gnome, nemo

I switched my file manager from nautilus to nemo. I installed nemo and changed in the files /usr/share/applicatons/nautilus-home.desktop and nautilus-folder-handler.desktop to

Exec=nemo

With nemo there appeared the icons for devices, homefolder and trashbin on the desktop and I want to remove them. I tried to disable them in the gconf-editor, but there is no "nautilus" under "apps", nor did i find any "show desktop" option. Desktop icons are also disabled via gnome-tweak-tool.

What else could I try? These icons are really ruining my desktop.

PS: I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Should do what you want